# Upgrading Angular1 project Angular4, CSS, Bootstrap, HTML

Tags: angularjs, angular, upgrade

[AngularJs correct view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3CsQ.png)I am upgrading angular1 project to angular4. Currently, I am working on views. But some views have problem they are not getting custom CSS of the theme. I have placed all the CSS files in the project and gave path in angular-cli-json. I have also tried after importing my css in style.scss but the view is same.

[Angualar4 view not rendered correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb1bQ.png)

Comment: This question is incredibly vague. You're going to need to give us a lot more details to get any kind of help. Do you have a repository we can look at?

Comment: An AngularJS 1.x project can't be upgraded to Angular, it has to be written with new guidelines of Angular.

Comment: I have updated my question and added screenshots of both views.

Answer (score 0):

If defining path in angular-cli.json is not working then you can import your files in /src/style.scss like
`@import "./assets/css/your-file.css";`
or
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700');`

Comment: Thank You Waiba for you assistance. I have also tried by importing files in style.scss but the view rendered is same. I have updated my question and added screenshots of both views.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then just adding class="form-control" in input element should work. as .btn seems to be working.. check your code or add some screenshots of code.